# mobx list updated,but rerender didn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

"mobx-react": "^5.3.6",
  "react": "^16.6.3",
      "antd": "^3.10.3",

i'm using mobx-react ,observe a object-list.The val in list was changed,but the page didn't rerender

data-structure

list=[{
id:1
status:1,
...
}]

worked

```js
this.items.replace(this.items);
```

not worked

```js
 @observable.deep items = [];
```

```js
@observer
class TableList extends Component {
  @observable items = [];//my list
...

  toggleOnline(data) {
    const { id, status } = data;
    const temp_status = status == 2 ? 1 : 2;
    ajax.post('page/switch', {
      id, status: temp_status
    }).then(action(() => {

      data.status = temp_status;
      message.success('操作成功');
    })).catch(err => {
      message.error(err);
    });
  }


render(){


 return

...
 <aonClick={this.toggleOnline.bind(this, record)}>{record.status == 2 || record.status == -1 ? '启用' : '停用'}</a>

...

 <Table
              rowKey="id"
              loading={loading}
              dataSource={this.items.toJS()}
              columns={this.columns}
              onChange={this.handleStandardTableChange}
            />

}

}
```

Comment: Please include your entire React component, or ideally create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in e.g. [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) so that it will be easier for someone to help you. You might have forgotten to use the [`@observer`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observer-component.html) decorator on your React component.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: 
[What does MobX react to?](https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html)

section: `Incorrect: store a local reference to an observable object without tracking`

```
const author = message.author;
autorun(() => {
    console.log(author.name)
})
message.author.name = "Sara";
message.author = { name: "John" };
```

> The first change will be picked up, message.author and author are the
>   same object, and the .name property is dereferenced in the autorun.
>   However the second change will not be picked up, the message.author
>   relation is not tracked by the autorun. Autorun is still using the
>   "old" author.

You should not re-assign observable variables.

Comment: could you share to me the best practice of such a object-list with mobx ?